# improvements to Least frequently used algorithm in O(1) run time complexity for cache

Tags: caching, networking, operating-system

I am implementing least frequently used algorithm using doubly linked list for cache eviction scheme in `O(1)` run time complexity. Now I am looking for ways to make it  faster or improve space and time complexity. Please use this for more details regarding implementation- http://dhruvbird.com/lfu.pdf

Comment: Please post what code you have attempted so far.

Comment: There can be a lot of churn of the frequency nodes if discarded when they are empty and allocated when starting a new bucket. You may wish to have a free list to reuse them instead. Alternatively you can retain the popularity in a sketch (see [article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2016/1/25/design-of-a-modern-cache.html)) which lets you capture the frequencies of all items (not just those in the working set).

Comment: Thanks you Mr.  Ben Manes , That helped me a lot